# What's the cleanest way to check if a file/directory exists in a Chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

A cookbook I work on uses `remote_directory` as a mean of copying user homes.

A user home may not exist in the cookbook though, in which case, `remote_directory` should not do anything for that resource.

I'm finding hard though, to cleanly perform this check. The resource doesn't seem to provide any way to test the existence of the source, and I can't reliably use the chef cache, because I've observed that in some cases, files are not purged from the cache, so I can't use a simple `Dir.exists?` check.

Therefore, I'm currently using `run_context.cookbook_collection['users'].all_files` in order to perform such test.

Is this the best possible practice I can apply for this case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way to do this, or indeed any supported way at all. We do not recommend poking around in Chef’s internal data structures for this or anything else as we reserve the right to change those at any time with no deprecation warnings or whatnot. The best you can do is to ignore the error using the eponymous resource property, if on a newer version of Chef you can at least use the silent mode variant of that.